# How wordpress theme and plugin update work from remote server

Tags: wordpress, http, server, wordpress-theming, auto-update

Actually how wordpress theme and plugin update working. What is it's core `class` to handle this system. How wordpress handle this `HTTP` request from remote server.

Can you help me to give some `basic guide`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Core Class:**

```
...\wp-includes\update.php
```

`update.php file` Checks against the WordPress server at api.wordpress.org server. Will only check if WordPress isn't installing.

```
//Every 12 hours it check version
function wp_version_check(){}
//If Available new plugin version than call
function wp_update_plugins(){}
//If Available new theme version than call
function wp_update_themes(){}
```

**How It Works:**

Every 12 hours, your WordPress blog will check for new plugin versions and store the request sent and response received in a site transient called `'update_plugins'`. The following code will display the content of this transient:

```
add_filter ('pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins', 'display_transient_update_plugins');
function display_transient_update_plugins ($transient)
{
    var_dump($transient);
}
```

After 12 hours or so, refresh your blog plugins page and you should get a similar output to the following:

```
object(stdClass)[18]
  public 'last_checked' => int 1333808132
  public 'checked' => 
    array
      'access/access.php' => string '1.0' (length=3)
      'adpress/wp-adpress.php' => string '3.1' (length=3)
          ...
      'wp-paypal/plug.php' => string '1.0' (length=3)
  public 'response' => 
    array
      'akismet/akismet.php' => 
        object(stdClass)[13]
          public 'id' => string '15' (length=2)
          public 'slug' => string 'akismet' (length=7)
          public 'new_version' => string '2.5.5' (length=5)
          public 'url' => string 'http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/akismet/' (length=44)
          public 'package' => string 'http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/akismet.2.5.5.zip' (length=55)
      'update.tmp/plugin.php' => 
        object(stdClass)[12]
          public 'slug' => string 'plugin' (length=6)
          public 'new_version' => string '1.1' (length=3)
          public 'url' => string 'http://localhost/update.php' (length=27)
          public 'package' => string 'http://localhost/update.php' (length=27)
```

The 12 hour waiting period is defined in WordPress core on Line 223 of the wp-includes/update.php file, it's the `$timeout` variable.

Version compare and check for new version:

```
// If a newer version is available, add the update
    if (version_compare(1.2, 1.3, '<')) {
        $obj = new stdClass();
        $obj->slug = $this->slug;
        $obj->new_version = $remote_version;
        $obj->url = $this->update_path;
        $obj->package = $this->update_path;
        $transient->response[$this->plugin_slug] = $obj;
    }
```

After check version if have new version. Wordpress handle update by this filter-

```
add_filter ('pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins', 'display_transient_update_plugins');
function display_transient_update_plugins ($transient)
{
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->slug = 'hello.php';
    $obj->new_version = '1.9';
    $obj->url = 'http://anyurl.com';
    $obj->package = 'http://anyurl.com';
    $transient['hello.php'] => $obj;
    return $transient;
}
```

**Handle this HTTP request from remote server:**

There have three tutorial for update wordpress plugin and theme from remote server-
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-the-wordpress-http-api-automatic-plugin-updates--wp-25181

http://w-shadow.com/blog/2010/09/02/automatic-updates-for-any-plugin/ [Only for Apache server]

https://kaspars.net/blog/wordpress/automatic-updates-for-plugins-and-themes-hosted-outside-wordpress-extend

> Hope it would be helpful.